# Can I bring a cooking knife to the Maldives?

Tags: luggage, legal, maldives, cold-weapons

My sister and I are travelling to Maldives the paradise Island.
We want to bring cooking knife and some cooking paste for our cooking.
Can we check in our sharp cooking knife in our check in luggage?

We will be travelling via budget airline and must we declare with the custom on arrival in Male?

Comment: Cooking knifes in the check-in should be fine. I just did this last week.

Comment: Cooking paste should be seen as a liquid, I guess, and as such should be in your check in luggage, or if packed in containers under 100 ml (or 3.4 oz) you can have it in your liquids bag in your hand luggage. But do check with customs on arrival whether you can bring it, some countries do not allow some substances and I have not checked for yours.

Comment: any sharp/pointed objects are not allowed in any airlines to any destination.

Answer (score 2):

Knives, and similar items that might be used as weapons but are not a danger to the aircraft, can be carried in checked baggage. Check with your airline if you are in doubt.

For customs purposes a cooking knife won't be treated any differently from anything else. As long as you are not importing it you won't be charged import duty.

Some countries have restrictions on knife possession, but all that I know of have exemptions for cooking knives. If it were a hunting knife or similar you would have to check for restrictions.

Comment: +1 It's probably worth noting that for _immigration_ purposes a complete set of professional cooking knives might be interpreted as evidence that you intend to work illegally in the country you are entering.